# I am looking for a classification word to describe words with multiple, disparate meanings, for example, train. Poly-meaning-al? LOL

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing an article about data mapping, and discussing the various types of challenges in mapping data elements from one system to another.  One of these challenges is assuming that a data element called X in one system is the same as a data element named X in a different system, simply because they are named the same.

I am looking for a classification for words that have multiple, disparate meanings.  My mind keeps jumping to polynomial, but I need that type of word that would relate to the meaning of words.  Poly-meaning-al?

Answer (score 2):

The word **polysemous** might be what you're looking for. [TFD defines it as:](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/polysemous)

> Having or characterized by many meanings, as the words *play* and *table.*

Comment: This answer is spot on. A variant is *polysemic*.